# UML- association with attributes

Tags: uml

With reference to UML, a *n*-ary association without attributes between *n* classes can be defined as subset of a Cartesian product of the sets made of instances of the *n* classes.

Since the association is a set of

```
n-tuple := {(I1,I2,...,In),...}.
```

Now, if the n-ary association has *k* attributes, is an element of it still defined as *n*-tuple or is it a *n+k*-tuple (and so the association is a set of *n+k*-tuple)?.

Comment: What do you mean by Association attribute? Are you thinking of an Association Class and its attributes?

Comment: @Ister I think so. For example if Major is the association between classes Person and City , an attribute of Mayor could be a String that represents the elction' s day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a class has k attributes, its objects can be represented as k-tuples corresponding to the rows of a relational database table with k columns.

In the UML, an instance of an association is called a *link*. A link of an n-ary association can be represented as an n-tuple corresponding to a row of a relational database table with n columns.

In UML, an *association class* is an association that has attributes like a class. For instance, the binary association class `ExamParticipation` is both an association between the classes `Exam` and `Student` and it is also a class defining the attribute `grade`.

When an n-ary association class has k attributes, its instances can be represented as (n+k)-tuples corresponding to the rows of a relational database table with n+k columns.

Epilog: Notice, however, that a UML association cannot be identified with the mathematical concept of a relation (as a subset of a Cartesian Product), since UML admits of associations having the same link more than once (when association ends are characterized as non-unique), thus not being sets, but multi-sets.

Comment: @JimL.that's why I've asked anjelo in a comment to his question what does he mean by attributes of association and he confirmed that it's about attributes of a class for association class. There is nothing that forbids association class to be an n-ary association. Specification says only that association is simultaneously an association (of any kind so for instance it can be an n-ary association) and a class. Note also that the question was edited to such extend that it might be unclear now that we're still talking about n-ary association when we discuss added k attributes.

Comment: @Ister, I agree n-ary ass class is legal. Although, making links for them between instance specs and having slot values is a challenge in some if not all tools.

Comment: @gwag: Oh, I think I meant to put that comment on Thomas' answer, where he said, "A n-ary association is equivalent to an association class the connects n class." Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I upvoted your answer to make it up to you.  I don't understand why your answer isn't the accepted one.

Comment: @JimL. Because the OP is not (yet) a frequent visitor of SO and likely has not noticed the trend.

Answer (score 0):

It's still n-tuple.

Note, each of the classes involved in an n-ary association can also have its own attributes. If you include those attributes it would have to be some gigantic -tuple. The association however is related only to it's ownedEnds.

However just for better understanding you could eventually consider n+1-tuple where n are ownedEnds and extra class is the one describing association. But this is not what the specification says so treat it only as a thought experiment.